# Calculate time passed variable to use in $.get()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update my database with some information. One of the key pieces of information is how much time has passed since the page first loaded and when the user click a button. My code looks like this:

```
<script>
function pauseVideo() {
    $.get("video_pause.php?pause=" + timePassed + "&videoid=<?php echo $_GET['sessionid']; ?>&sessionid=<?php echo $_GET['videoid']; ?>");
}
</script>
```

and

```
<html>
<div id="pause" onclick="pauseVideo()">PAUSE</div>
</html>
```

My PHP is fine so ignore that. The part I'm having trouble with is the 'timePassed'. I need this to be the amount of time in seconds since the page was first loaded and the person clicks the PAUSE div.

I think I need to run a function on click to find the passed time and then use that time variable in the $.get() somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
var startTime = (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
function pauseVideo() {
    var curTime = (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
    var timePassed = Math.floor(curTime - startTime);
    $.get("video_pause.php?pause=" + timePassed + "&videoid=<?php echo $_GET['sessionid']; ?>&sessionid=<?php echo $_GET['videoid']; ?>");
}
```

Comment: take the floor value of timePassed.

Comment: Where are you defining getTime()? Am I supposed to do this beforehand: var d = new Date(); var n = d.getTime(); ?

Comment: @AzzyDude sorry, I was too hasty, my answer was incomplete, you need the `Date` object.

Comment: Okay, yeah, so it looks like this: var d = new Date();
var startTime = d.getTime() / 1000;
function pauseVideo() {
 var d = new Date();
    var curTime = d.getTime() / 1000;
    var timePassed = Math.floor(curTime - startTime);
 $.get("video_pause.php?pause=" + timePassed + "&videoid=<?php echo $_GET['sessionid']; ?>&sessionid=<?php echo $_GET['videoid']; ?>");
}

Answer (score 1):

When the document loads, just save the current time in a variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeWhenLoaded = (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
});
```

Then, when the pause button is clicked, calculate the time that has passed:

```
function pauseVideo() {
    var currTime = (new Date).getTime() / 1000;
    // time in seconds
    var timePassed = Math.floor(currTime - timeWhenLoaded);
    $.get("video_pause.php?pause=" + timePassed + "&videoid=<?php echo $_GET['sessionid'];     ?>&sessionid=<?php echo $_GET['videoid']; ?>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the onclick in your HTML, and remove your existing function, then put this in the head section of your page:

```
(function(){
    var loadTime = (new Date).getTime(); // Page started loading

    $(function(){
        // DOM fully loaded, so move the assignment here if that is what
        // you want to consider as the load time

        $('#pause').click(function(){
            $.get("video_pause.php?pause=" + Math.floor(((new Date).getTime() - loadTime)/1000) + "&videoid=<?php echo $_GET['sessionid']; ?>&sessionid=<?php echo $_GET['videoid']; ?>");
        });
    });

})();
```

Also note that you can never trust that variable on the server side. Anyone could input a negative number or even the word 'pizza' for the value if they really want to.

Answer (score -1):

if the page with the following code is generated server-side, you can either just pass the current time to the script, as in:

```
<html>
  <div id="pause" onclick="pauseVideo('" + curTime +"')">PAUSE</div>
</html>
```

(needs echo syntax)

or put it in a hidden field and pass it back to the server. (and do your calculations in php)
this way, you get the time passed since the page was requested...